# Unknown error in administration console on fresh new server

Tags: couchbase

I'm a pure newbie with couchbase.

I have downloaded and installed couchbase server 4 Community Edition on a windows 10 workstation.

I loaded the sample data bucket gamesim and created a new databucket for my needs.

In the web administration console, i see the 2 data buckets and i can create a new one.
But i can't create document or see documents on the 2 data buckets (sample and mine) or on a new one.

The console display :

> Error: unknown error
>   ({exit,{{bad_return_value,{stop,{error,couldnt_connect_to_memcached}}},
>   {gen_server,call, [{'ns_memcached-gamesim-sample','ns_1@127.0.0.1'},
>   {get_keys,[0,1,2,3,4,5...1023], [{include_docs,true},
>   {inclusive_end,true}, {limit,6}, {start_key,undefined},
>   {end_key,undefined}]}, infinity]}}})

and the create document button is disabled

An idea on this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After search, i found in log tab several errors:

> Service 'memcached' exited with status 255. Restarting.

and i found a related article [here](http://btburnett.com/2016/09/couchbase-server-and-windows-10-anniversary-edition-problems.html) : Couchbase 4.5 is not supported on windows 10 anniversary edition. It seems that 4.6 developper preview is supported

Comment: Yes, there was a known problem with W10 AE.  You wouldn't use Windows for production, so getting to understand Couchbase using the Developer Preview will get you going.  Otherwise you might want to create a Linux VM to work with for the time being.

Comment: I have win 10 enterprise, and similar issues, fresh installation but memcache crashes